# Running the Gatsby cli behind the company firewall

Tags: gatsby

I am unable to clone the gatsby-starter-default.git using the gatsby cli as it is using the 'git' url which is being blocked by our firewall rules

I tried to add the following to git config as well but still no joy

*git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://*

Below is the output...

```
gatsby new gatsby-site
2017-10-24T20:57:34-0500 <log> init-starter.js:107 (clone) Cloning git repo git://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default.git to gatsby-site...
2017-10-24T21:00:04-0500 <error> new.js:12 () Error: Git clone error: Cloning into 'gatsby-site'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
```

Is there a way to force the cli to use https:// instead of git://

Answer (score 3):

Just clone the starter directly.

`gatsby new` is a convenience but not required. What it does is:

1. Shallow clone a repo
2. Delete the .git directory (so you aren't saddled with the git history of the starter)
3. Run npm or yarn install

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Per the [Gatsby starter](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-starters/) documentation, you can set the `URL` as a parameter:

```
gatsby new gatsby-site http://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default.git
```

Comment: Thanks Derek. I tried this but it still seems to be trying to pull the code using the git url.


`gatsby new gatsby-site https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default.git
2017-10-25T19:09:02-0500 <log> init-starter.js:107 (clone) Cloning git repo git://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default.git to gatsby-site...
2017-10-25T19:11:34-0500 <error> new.js:12 () Error: Git clone error: Cloning into 'gatsby-site'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out`